# Opening url.openstream throws invalid http response

Tags: java, http, url

I am trying to read a file from a temperature module, when I call openStream() on the url I receive an IOExeption with the message "Invalid Http response"

```
SEVERE: null
java.io.IOException: Invalid Http response
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1555)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1441)
at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1038)
at thermometerpoller.Poller.poll(Poller.java:38)
```

I can telnet to the temperature module:

```
telnet 192.168.142.55 80
Trying 192.168.142.55...
Connected to 192.168.142.55.
Escape character is '^]'.
GET /state.xml HTTP/1.1

<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<datavalues>
<units>F</units>
<sensor1temp>74.0</sensor1temp>
<sensor2temp>67.0</sensor2temp>
<sensor3temp>xx.x</sensor3temp>
<sensor4temp>xx.x</sensor4temp>
<relay1state>0</relay1state>
<relay2state>0</relay2state>
</datavalues>

Connection closed by foreign host.
```

It seems that the temperature module isn't sending any headers with the reply.
Unfortunately , when I look at [HttpURLConnection.java](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/484e16c0a040/src/share/classes/sun/net/www/protocol/http/HttpURLConnection.java) if there is no response code it throws the IOException.

My question is, is there a way to get the file contents with out caring what the response code is either via library or another method?

Comment: If you are using a firewall on your local system, disable it, and test. I faced similar issue, and later on i saw in firewall logs, it was blocking requests sent from my java program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the server is [not HTTP compliant](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec6.html#sec6), you shouldn't use URL or URLConnection.  Use a plain Socket instead:

```
Document doc;

final Socket connection = new Socket("192.168.142.55", 80);

try (final OutputStream out = connection.getOutputStream();
     InputStream in = connection.getInputStream()) {

    Callable<Void> requestSender = new Callable<Void>() {
        @Override
        public Void call()
        throws IOException {
            String request = "GET /state.xml HTTP/1.1\n\n";
            out.write(request.getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII));
            return null;
        }
    };
    ExecutorService background = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    Future<?> request = background.submit(requestSender);

    doc = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(in);

    request.get();
    background.shutdown();
}
```

Comment: This code closes the socket after sending the request, so how can it receive a response? NB The line terminator in HTTP is `\r\n`, not just `\n`.

Comment: @EJP You're right about the streams.  Updated.  As for the newlines, I'm just echoing what nelsonslament apparently typed in his raw telnet connection;  the server doesn't appear to follow the same rules as a real HTTP server.

Comment: FWIW a compliant telnet client sends end-of-line as CR LF (see RFC 854) and it is not coincidental RFCs specify that same end-of-line for HTTP-header and similar things like SMTP and FTP-command. Whether this server/device cares about CRLF vs LF vs maybe something else is unknown without more exact testing.